# C# Loading data adapter from excel, is there a maximum column count?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015

I'm running into an issue trying to create a c# data table from an excel spreadsheet. The code is simple but for some reason when I step through it, the data table only loads with 256 of the 700 columns that are in the spreadsheet. Looking at the code below, Settings.Excel_Proj_Select is just "Select * from Project_Data$". Is there a maximum column count and if so, is there a way around this to get the full sheet into a data table?

```
        public static DataTable getRowData()
        {

        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(Settings.ExcelCN);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand(Settings.Excel_Proj_Select, cnn);
        cnn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        cnn.Close();

        dt.Columns.Add("Extract_Date", typeof(string));
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            row["Extract_Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Any info is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If I am not wrong there is a limitations of 255 columns with OleDb and Excel. It is a limit in the OleDb code not in Excel. Try to use the [ExcelDataReader library](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a 255 max number of columns when using the Ole provider for this, yes.

But you can use a simple workaround by specifying the range in your queries:

```
//Modify the range to suit your needs
SELECT * FROM Project_Data$[RANGE]:[HERE]
```

You can then run multiple queries, each which SELECT different ranges, then combine the data.

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet) for another method using OpenXML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so you mean you just specify the range and you can go over the 255 limit? Or you just mean specify a range within the 255 allowable range? going to try now...

Comment: @user3494110 I'm not 100% positive, but it might.  If it doesn't, one thing you can definitely do is run multiple queries on separate ranges and then combine the results.  This allows you to use your OleDb connection to read as many columns as you want.  But will require you to combine data.

Comment: Dang, unfortunately it doesn't let you. If you specify a range up to the 255 column limit it works but any further it just says that the range is invalid and can't be found :(.

Comment: @user3494110 You can use separate queries that return 255 columns per each range.  So basically, read the excel file in pieces (one 255 column range at a time).  It's either that or don't use an OleDb connnection.